# MapFragment returns null after Using Calligraphy dependecy

Tags: android, fonts, mapfragment

I used Calligraphy for loading custom fonts. In my activity's i attached the Calligraphy wrapper like below

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

I am getting 
inflater = {CalligraphyLayoutInflater} in my onCreateView in my Fragment onCreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

And i am getting null in my MapFragment.

how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of wasted hours to find the actual problem, i found a quick fix for the time being. We can solve it by changing the `getChildFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`

I don't actually know why it behaves like that. But if you are looking for a quick fix you can use getFragmentManager() in your MapFragment.

You can follow the [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/274#) for updates on this issue

**EDIT 1:**

I still get this issue in some devices like one plus.